# How to find the number of distinct values from one column for a group of values from another column in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table named **Asset population** that looks like this:

| Serial Number | Product Family | Customer Name | Customer Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TV | Sam | cus1 |
| 2 | Radio | Sam | cus1 |
| 3 | Fridge | Sam | cus1 |
| 4 | TV | Ronny | cus2 |
| 5 | TV | Tina | cus3 |
| 6 | Fridge | Ronny | cus2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to add another column **Customer Size** grouped over Customer Number, with the following conditions:

- **Retail**, if number of distinct Product Family is between 1 to 3.
- **Small**, if number of distinct Product Family is between 4 to 19.
- **Medium**, if number of distinct Product Family is between 20 to 100.
- **Large**, if number of distinct Product Family is above 100.

To be exact, I want the Customer Number to fall into one of the above four categories.

I have tried using **VAR** with **GroupBY** but each time error comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **Calculated Column**:

```
=
VAR ThisCustomerNumber = [Customer Number]
VAR DistinctProductFamilyCount =
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT( Table1[Product Family] ),
        FILTER( Table1, Table1[Customer Number] = ThisCustomerNumber )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        DistinctProductFamilyCount <= 3,
        "Retail",
        IF(
            DistinctProductFamilyCount <= 19,
            "Small",
            IF( DistinctProductFamilyCount <= 100, "Medium", "Large" )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Wolley  maybe ``SWITCH`` ?

Comment: What if we add one more clause ie. "No Asset, if the number of distinct Product Family is=null". Because there are many rows with null values, it falls under the "Medium" customer size, which is incorrect.